# Is there any way to deselect all deselect all events that has been rendered using select callback with 'renderEvent' feature in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I use the select call back to render event. Is there any way to deselect all events that have  been rendered using select callback with 'renderEvent' feature in fullcalendar?

```
select: function(start, end) {
  var eventData = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'schedule',
    start: start,
    end: end,
  };
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
}
```

For all select operation i render the new events to full calendar.
So is there any way to clear all rendered events added through select callback.

Answer (score 0):

The removeEvents function (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/) removes events.

You need to specify the ID(s) to remove, or create a callback which decides which events to remove. Since you created the events in the first place, you should know their IDs in order to do this.

```
//to delete a single known ID
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', 123456);
```

or, something more sophisticated using a list of IDs held by you (the IDs of events you have previously created using the "select" callback, for example):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(evt) {
  var del = false;
  $.each(yourIDArray, function(index, value)
  {
    //if the ID matches one in the array, it should be deleted, so set the return value to true as per the docs
    if (evt.id == value) del = true;
    return false; //used to break out from the .each loop, no point continuing once we found it
  });
  return del;
});
```

This function can be used with any events on the calendar, not just ones created via a user selection.